# No Android project type in Eclipse->File->New-Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am running CentOS 5.5 x86_64 with JDK 1.6, Eclipse Galileo, and the 0.9.7 ADT is installed; however, after installation, the Android project type is not available. I have checked in the installed packages list and it is installed. Anybody encounter this problem before? Could it be due to my use of the 64-bit java VM that is installed on my system?

Answer (score 16):

This usually happens when you dont select any android SDK in "Preferences > Android" You just have to reset the perspective in eclipse, Windows > Reset Perspective.

Hope this is still helpful.

Comment: Resetting the perspective fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: RESET PERSPECTIVE fixes it.

Answer (score 10):

Hope you have already set the Android Preferences if not Window -> Preferences-> Android and browse to the android SDK folder.

In rare cases even after doing this step, Android Project option doesn't show up in File -> New. But you can get it by File -> New -> Project .. and choose the android project from the options displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Android in Windows->Preferences. I suppose I could try to uninstall/reinstall eclipse and the ADT...

Comment: Try resetting the perspective in Window > Reset Perspective. Please upvote @minimalistix answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I reinstalled eclipse and android. I think the problem was that I hadn't unpacked the android tools first. The plugin was installed, but it had nothing to talk to! Anyway, all the android related stuff now shows up in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows 7, 64-bit edition, with the latest Eclipse (Indigo) and the latest ADT plugin, I had the exact same problem.  No Android project type, no Android in Windows/Preferences.

Like @Rubberman I solved the problem by totally re-installing Eclipse.  Eclipse doesn't seem to use the standard Add/Remove Program stuff in Windows; I just deleted the Eclipse install directories and my Eclipse workspace directory, re-installed Eclipse, and re-installed the ADT plugin.

I would have liked to have just removed the plugin and re-installed without deleting the whole of my Eclipse install, but I couldn't figure out a way to do that.  I don't see any way to remove a plugin, and when I tried to choose ADT for installation Eclipse gave me an error, saying "I can't install that because it is already installed."

Answer (score 1):

I Know its a very old post..but still it may help someone with same problem...

I wanted to jst share that we can uninstall the plugins without the need of reinstalling eclipps..by simply going to 'already installed application' link and selecting all the android related options and simply clicking on uninstall button..Now you can add fresh android sdk to your ecllips..I have tried it and it works..

Hope, I helped aomeone..:-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, been looking for the answer to this for an hour, it's not well mentioned.

if you are using linux then you need to add 2 more things to install ADT correctly:

- GEF from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases
- WST Server Adapters from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/ (modify for your release)

do it the same as the adt plugin install.

maybe you need to uninstall then reinstall the adt plugin after?

sources:

- ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1595684
- sonalsantan.blogspot.com/2010/10/eclipse-adt-plugin-on-ubuntu-1010-after.html

Answer (score -1):

You have to install the Eclipse plugin called ADT.