# No Android project type available in Eclipse->File->New-Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I have installed latest JDK and ADT bundle package (I'm working under Windows 7, 32 bits OS)
I installed all the possibly needed packages in ADT Manager.
I defined ADT location in Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Android
But I still have no option to start File->New->Project->Android->Android Project or
File->New->Other->Android Project
I have many other options like:
Android Activity
Android Application Project
Android Icon Set
Android Object
Android Project from Existing Code 
Android Sample Project
Android test Project
etc..
But all these are not what I need.
I already looked on existing questions here like [No Android project type in Eclipse->File->New-Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999285/no-android-project-type-in-eclipse-file-new-project)  and others and also on several similar questions on other forums but still did not found an answer for my problem.

Comment: Did you do `Help/Check for Updates`? I once forgot to do that after upgrading my SDK, and I had a similar issue. And this solved the problem.

Comment: Sure, I checked for updates and installed many possibly required packages by SDK Manager. Checked for updates again - no updates available ;)

Comment: `many possibly required packages by SDK Manager` I use to check **all** and update **all**, after agreeing with **all** the license agreements (I also check **all** in SDK Manager - excluding the Google TV-addon, since marked as "non compatible with Windows").

Comment: I installed all the updates SDK suggested for me + packages possible will be used 9I'm going to work on several Android devices of different API levels). I Installed all them by 2-3 steps. Currently all the packages are installed. and I checked on Help->Ckeck for updates - no new updates available.

Comment: So, what else... I'd give a try to `File/Restart` (restarts Eclipse, not the system). You might also wanto to set up the path for your `JDK environment variable` in Windows and restart the system. As a last resort, in `Window/Preferences/Java/Installed JREs`, I'd set your JRE path.

Comment: This path is already set there too...

Comment: Did you try all the 3 advices I gave you in the last comment? Because I finished my ideas...

Comment: I see 2 advices there. yes, I tried. Nothing new. I also tried to switch and reset perspective as advised here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649562/eclipse-with-android-sdk-missing-menu-items....

Comment: 3, marked in gray: 1 - Restart Eclipse, 2 - Set Windows environment path for your JDK and restart Windows, 3 - Set the JRE path in Eclipse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57516/discussion-between-eliyahu-and-frank-n-stein).

Comment: I guess Android Application Project is what you are looking for. What you want to do exactly? By android project means android application or something specific you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Android Application Project. What exactly do you think Android Project is? You are trying to create an applicaiton, correct? Then Android Application Project is what you want.

There is no "Android Project" option. In fact, I've never seen it. Basically, you have the following:

Android Activity - you just want to create an activity
Android Application Project - This creates a complete android application project to create an application that you can install and launch on an android device.
Android Project from Existing Code - import existing code into an Android Project

There are many more as you found out. But, most of the time, you would use Android Application Project.

You don't really specify what it is you are looking at creating specifically, so I'm going to assume this is what you want.

If you could give more information as to exactly what you think "Android Project" is for and what you are trying to accomplish with it, that would help.

Per the ADT tutorial site, they have the instructions on creating an Android Project, which is generic. There are numerous types of Android Project, with the Android Application Project being one of them. Not sure if this is where you are getting the name "Android Project" from or not. Here is the link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Everything you state at this point shows you have installed ADT correctly and it's integrated properly with Eclipse.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I'll check this tomorrow. I didn't mention in the question but my problem is that I'm trying to start learning Robotium. Here https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumTutorials they have step-by-step tutorial so I stopped on Design Simple Android Calculator Application step after Setting Up Android Working Environment. They mentioned there that I will see "Android Project" but I did not see that option. So, again, I will check this. Maybe they just were not too exact... ;)